# Housekeeping reports with shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ubuntu

I am working with an application that creates fresh reports every half hour and there is a requirement to do housekeeping to clear down the files.

Different type of reports are created and persisted in directories as follows:

```
/home/myapp/reports/report1/
/home/myapp/reports/report2/
/home/myapp/reports/report3/
/home/myapp/reports/report4/
```

There is requirement to housekeep and delete files older than lets say 3 days in all the above directories. Instead of writing a line of script for each directory e.g.

```
find /home/myapp/reports/report1/ -type f -mtime +3 -delete
find /home/myapp/reports/report2/ -type f -mtime +3 -delete
find /home/myapp/reports/report3/ -type f -mtime +3 -delete
```

Is there a way I can write a generic one that will support future additional type of reports as well as those above? How would this look like? What if older than days is different for each report type and not 3 days for all?

Answer (score 1):

You can use globs to include all of them:

```
find /home/myapp/reports/report*/ -type f -mtime +3 -delete
```

If you need a different number of days for different directories, your simplest solution is usually to create differently named directories. For example, to keep three copies of daily and weekly reports:

```
find /home/myapp/reports/daily/report*/ -type f -mtime +3 -delete
find /home/myapp/reports/weekly/report*/ -type f -mtime +21 -delete
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a file listing each directory and the expiration date, example,

```
$ cat /home/myapp/etc/report-cleanup.csv
/home/myapp/reports/report1/ 3
/home/myapp/reports/report2/ 7
/home/myapp/reports/report3/ 5
/home/myapp/reports/daily/ 3
/home/myapp/reports/weekly/ 21
...
```

Then have your script read each line and process individually,

```
$ cat /home/myapp/util/report-cleanup.sh
#!/bin/bash
config="/home/myapp/etc/report-cleanup.csv"
cat $config |while read dir expire; do
    echo "path: $dir, expire: $expire"
    find $dir -type f -mtime +$expire -delete
end
```

You could run each find in the background (&), or use the ordering in the file as the order to search and remove files.